# Isometric embedding of SO(3) into an euclidean space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometries

Consider $SO(3)$ with its bi-invariant metric and $R^n$ the euclidean space of dimension $n$. What is the minimal value of $n$ such that there exists an isometric embedding $f: SO(3) \to R^n$?

Comment: $SO(3) \cong \mathbb{R}P^3$, and I think the minimal $n$ for $\mathbb{R}P^k$ is $k+2$, but I can't remember.

Comment: But the question is for isometric embeddings for the bi-invariant metric.

Comment: $SO(3)$ is the unit tangent bundle to $S^2$. Since $S^2$ has an isometric embedding into Euclidean 3-space $\mathbb{R}^3$, and the tangent space to $\mathbb{R}^3$ is isometric to $\mathbb{R}^6$, we get an isometric embedding of $SO(3)$ into $\mathbb{R}^6$. However, I'm not sure if the induced metric is the bi-invariant metric (I suspect not, given Robert's comments).

Answer (score 22):

About embeddings, I don't know, but there is an isometric *immersion* of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ with its bi-invariant metric into $\mathbb{R}^7$.

To see this, consider the natural representation $\rho_3:\mathrm{SO}(3)\to\mathrm{SO}\big({\mathcal{H}}_3\bigr)$, where $\mathcal{H}_3$ is the $7$-dimensional space consisting of the harmonic cubic polynomials on $\mathrm{R}^3$.  This is an irreducible representation, so up to multiples there is a unique inner product on $\mathcal{H}_3$ that is invariant under this $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ action.  Endow $\mathcal{H}_3$ with this inner product.

The stabilizer of the element $h = x_1x_2x_3\in\mathcal{H}_3$ is a 12-element discrete subgroup $A$ (isomorphic to $A_4$). The metric induced on $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ by the immersion $\iota:\mathrm{SO}(3)\to \mathcal{H}_3$ defined by $\iota(a) = \rho_3(a)h$ is clearly left-invariant and it is also invariant under right multiplication by elements of $A$.  Since conjugation by elements of $A$ acts irreducibly on the Lie algebra of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, it follows that this induced left-invariant metric is fully right invariant and hence is a multiple of the bi-invariant metric.  Replacing $h$ by any nonzero multiple of $h$, we can scale the induced metric arbitrarily, so we can get any (positive) multiple of the bi-invariant metric that we want.

Note, however, that $\iota$ is an isometric embedding of $\mathrm{SO}(3)/A$, not $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ itself.  It seems very likely to me that this isometric immersion can be isometrically perturbed to an isometric embedding, but I haven't tried to check that yet.

Actually, I suspect that there is an isometric embedding into $\mathbb{R}^6$, but there is certainly not an equivariant one, and, if it does exist, it might be hard to find.

Comment: How about taking two copies of the standard representation of $ SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $? The six dimensional (reducible) $ SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $ representation $ \mathbb{R}^3 \oplus \mathbb{R}^3 $ has the property that for any pair of linearly independent vectors $ v,w \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ the vector $ (v,w) \in  \mathbb{R}^3 \oplus \mathbb{R}^3  $ has trivial stabilizer and so orbit $ \mathbb{R}P^3 $. (if $ v,w $ are linearly dependent but not both 0 the orbit is a sphere $ S^2 $ and the orbit of $ (0,0) $ is trivial of course). Is this embedding isometric? It at least has nice equivariance properties.

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira:  That always gives you a left-invariant metric on $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, but it is never a biïnvariant metric on $\mathrm{SO}(3)$.

Comment: Ok that's kind of what I expected. Is it possible for the metric on this orbit $ \mathbb{R}P^3 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^6 $ to be round? Or is it always squashed in one direction like the Berger sphere $ S^3 $? I guess a biinvariant $ \mathbb{R}P^3\cong S^3/-I $ would have to be round since the (orientation preserving) isometry group is $ SO_4/-I\cong SO_3 \times SO_3 $. So for my embedding of $ \mathbb{R}P^3  $ in $ \mathbb{R}^6 $ would it have to be isometric to the unit tangent bundle of round $ S^2 $ and have isometry group $ O_3 $?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira:  The actual metric depends on the choice of $v$ and $w$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  If $v$ and $w$ are an orthonormal pair, then, yes, the induced metric on the orbit will be isometric to the unit tangent bundle of round (unit) S^2.  The isometry group of that guy is actually 4-dimensional:  The obvious $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ plus the $S^1$ action on the circle fibers.

Comment: I am interesting in perturbing this to be an actual embedding of $ \mathbb{R}P^3 $ into $ \mathbb{R}^7 $ as you suggested above. In other words, finding a harmonic cubic polynomial with trivial stabilizer (rather than $ A_4 $ stabilizer for $ xyz$ ). Maybe $ xyz+x^3+3x^2y-3xy^2-y^3 $? I asked a question about this on MSE and Gavin Ball said you personally communicated a factorization result for these polynomials https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4362071/vector-with-trivial-stabilizer-in-so-3-representation. I was wondering if you could expand on that or if you had any references.

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira:  It's easy to choose a harmonic cubic with trivial $\mathrm{SO}(3)$-stabilizer:  Take the harmonic part of the product $x(y+ax)(z+bx+cy)$ for generic small numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$.  However, the induced metric on the $\mathrm{SO}(3)$-orbit of this harmonic cubic won't be a bi-invariant metric on $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, it will only be left-invariant.  A proof of the `factorization lemma' that Gavin Ball referred to in that MSE posting is in an unpublished manuscript of mine. I've never seen it in any reference, but it's not hard to prove.

Answer (score 8):

the nine matrix elements of $SO(3)$ represent a vector in $R^9$, see [Isometric Embedding for Homogeneous Compact 3-Manifolds](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02113094) (1996).

Comment: But of course there are lots of relations - elements above the diagonal determine the elements below the diagonal, determinant is $1$, etc.  So $9$ is certainly not minimal.

Comment: @PaulSiegel --- yes, 9 seems large, but unless I have misunderstood section 8 of the cited paper it is minimal.

Comment: This is the same as the Veronese embedding $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^3\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^9$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Doesn't they state that for $r_3 = 0$ one gets isometric embedding into $\mathbb{R}^6$?

Comment: It it easy to see that we can't do better if we want the action of $SO(3) \times SO(3)$ to extend linearly to $\mathbb{R}^n$: Irreducible representations of $SO(3)$ have dimension $2m+1$, so irreps of $SO(3) \times SO(3)$ have dimension $(2m+1) \times (2n+1)$, so the smallest representation of the product on which neither $SO(3)$ acts trivially is dimension $3 \times 3=9$. But it isn't clear to me that the symmetries have to extend to the ambient space.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker:  Section 8 of the paper you cite only proves that the matrix embedding of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ into $\mathbb{R}^9$ does not lie in a hyperplane (which was obvious from the beginning anyway).  It says nothing about whether or not there is an isometric embedding of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ into a lower dimensional space.

Comment: @VítTuček:  No.  In their paper, they explicitly point out that the embedding into $\mathbb{R}^6$ that one gets for $r_3=0$ is *not* isometric for the bi-invariant metric.  (Of course, it *is* isometric for a different left-invariant metric, just not the bi-invariant one.)

Comment: @RobertBryant: I don't see that statement anywhere in the paper. Rather it seems that they obtain embedding of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ only for special choice $r_\mu = 1$, $\mu = 1, 2, 3$. For $r_3 = 0$ one basically gets the embedding you've described in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/161295/isometric-embedding-of-so3-into-an-euclidean-space#comment412031_161305

Comment: @VítTuček:  However, they compute the induced metric embedding parameters explicitly and relate them to the $r_\mu$ in their equations $(55)$ and $(56)$, and it's obvious from these formulae that they don't get the bi-invariant metric when $r_3=0$.  That's what I mean by 'explicitly point out'.

Comment: @RobertBryant: I see. Don't you mean equations (29) - (31)?

Comment: @VítTuček:  Yes, you are right; equations (29–31).  The others are for an embedding into an indefinite space; I was too hasty when I was looking back at the file.

Comment: @RobertBryant: Thank you for clearing this up.

Answer (score 6):

[Apparently](http://www.lehigh.edu/~dmd1/immtable), Hopf proved in [H] that the projective space $\mathbb{R}P^3$ embedds into $\mathbb{R}^5$ and Hantzsche [Ha] proved that it cannot be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^4$.  Since this projective space is isomorphic to $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ as was noted by Paul Siegel, this at least gives a lower bound. Let me just add that $\mathrm{Spin}(3)$ is (isomorphic to) the unit sphere in quaternions and hence this double cover of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ is embeddable into $\mathbb{R}^4$.

[H] H.Hopf, "Systeme symmetrischer Bilinearformen und euklidische Modelle
     der projektiven Raume", Vierteljschr Naturforsch Gesellschaft Zurich
     85 (1940) 165-177.

[Ha] W.Hantzsche, "Einlagerung von Mannigfaltigkeiten in euklidische
     Raume", Math Zeit 43 (1938) 38-58.

Comment: But the question is about isometric embedding for a specific metric. A flat torus embeds as a submanifold in 3-space but not isometrically, for example.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez OP did not specify the class of embeddings, if it is $C^1$ then by Nash--Kuiper there is one, for $C^\infty$-embeddings 9 might be the best.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin, yeah, sure. We all default to $C^\infty$, though :-)

Comment: Right. :) I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: The embedding isn't hard to see. $SO(3)$ acts (by conjugation) on the space of $3 \times 3$ symmetric matrices of trace $0$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^5$. A generic $SO(3)$ orbit in this space is isomorphic to $SO(3)$. But that isn't isometric, at least not for a general orbit.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: Actually, no.  The generic orbit in this $\mathbb{R}^5$ is not $\mathrm{SO}(3)$; it is a quotient $\mathrm{SO}(3)/(\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2)$.  This is because the generic $3$-by-$3$ symmetric matrix with trace zero and distinct eigenvalues is stabilized by the subgroup of order $4$ that fixes the eigenspaces.  Moreover, *none* of the metrics induced on these orbits is bi-invariant.

Comment: If you want to embed $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ into $\mathbb{R}^5$ (non-isometrically), the simplest way I know is to first embed it into $\mathbb{R}^6$ by projecting onto the first two columns of the matrix element in $\mathrm{SO}(3)$.  Then, note that the image of this embedding lies in a hypersphere $S^5\subset \mathbb{R}^6$.  Remove a point of this $S^5$ that does not lie in the image and then stereographically project this complement onto $\mathbb{R}^5$.  This gives a non-isometric, non-equivariant embedding of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ into $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Comment: Here's an easier (to me anyway) non-isometric embedding: SO(3) is the unit sphere bundle of $S^2$, and hence bounds the Euler class 2 disk bundle over the 2-sphere, say $W$. Doubling $W$ gives $S^2 \times S^2$, which bounds $S^2 \times B^3$, which embeds in $\mathbb{R}^5$ as a neighborhood of $S^2$.  Essentially the same argument shows that every orientable $3$-manifold embeds in $\mathbb{R}^5$, a result of Hirsch.

Comment: @DannyRuberman: OK.  However, it's already obvious that $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ embeds into $S^2\times S^2$ as order pairs of orthonormal vectors, so you don't need to mention the disk bundle.  After that, any way you get $S^2\times S^2$ embedded into $\mathbb{R}^5$ does the job.  Your way, you do need to know that the normal bundle of $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^5$ is trivial, which is not completely obvious (to me, anyway; I had to think about it).

Comment: @RobertBryant: Well, I'd say that it's straightforward that the normal bundle of $S^2$ is trivial; there is a series of embeddings $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R^3} \subset \mathbb{R^4} \subset \mathbb{R^5}$, each of which has trivial normal bundle. But everyone has their own idea of `obvious'.

Answer (score 3):

[This paper (I. Oszvath and B. Schuking, 1996)](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s24/sh/2e97266e-d345-4755-a254-d98fb5c27e40/ef3741ee2b7f7151dd3509cc248b624f) seems to construct the embedding into $\mathbb{R}^9$ and seem to be claiming that there is not one int $\mathbb{R}^6,$ or any lower-than-9 dimensional space.

Comment: yep, that's the one I cited (but only found the paywall link)

Comment: However, as I pointed out above, this paper does *not* prove that there is no isometric embedding of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ with its bi-invariant metric into a lower dimensional space than $\mathbb{R}^9$.  What the authors show is that their constructions don't yield such an embedding into any lower dimension.

Comment: @RobertBryant Yes, that bears out my impression, though since the authors are physicists, it is a little hard to figure out what they mean...

Answer (score 0):

SO(3), a 3-dimensional rotation is determined by a choice of axis, an element of $\mathbf{RP}^2$, and the amount of rotation, a number in $[0,2\pi)$. So  should it not be possible with  a number 1 more than that of projective plane?

Comment: An element of $SO(3)$ is determined by an element of $S^2$ and a rotation around that pole, not an element of $RP^2$. As a bundle over $RP^2$, it has disconnected fibers. So your argument suggests an embedding in $\mathbb{R}^4$, which is unlikely.

Comment: @ Ben: Not sure I understand. Why  should it  be $S^2$?  For a unit vector $v\in \mathbf{R}^3$ and $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ is not the 3d-rotation corresponding to the pair $(v,\theta)$  the same as that for $(-v,\theta)$? I guess it should be $\mathbf{RP}^2$.

Comment: This description in terms of $(\nu,\theta)$ is very messy; you have to identify $(\nu,\theta)$ with $(-\nu,2\pi-\theta)$, but you also have to collapse every element $(\nu,0)$ into the identity matrix, so topologically you get quite a monster. So your description is not as natural as thinking of $SO(3)$ as the unit tangent bundle of the sphere.

Comment: I see your objection. If we banish $\theta=0$ the remaining part should be topologically a non-monster, and can the whole thing be regarded as one-point compactification of that thing? Assuming there is a connection between minimal embedding dimensions of a manifold and its one-point compactification this might be useful. Is this approach worthwhile?

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer at all.)

If a metric space $X$ admits an isometric embedding into Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^n$, then all [Caley--Menger determinants](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html) defined by $n+2$ points from $X$ are equal to 0. Moreover, for a metric space embeddable into some $\mathbb{R}^N$ with large $N$ (this is our case) the above property guarantees that the image of such embedding lies in an $n$-dimensional subspace. It allows to get the minimal dimension for any specific metric, but there are many bi-invariant metrics, this is the problem.

Comment: I don't want to edit your answer, but receipt -> recipe . To make your recipe work for $SO(n)$ (or even $SO(3)$ you need to have an explicit polynomial in the matrix entries which gives the (squared) distance between two matrices. It is plausible that such a polynomial exists for $S^3,$ but less clear that it does for $SO(3).$

Comment: @IgorRivin Thank you, I fixed the spelling. Now I see what is the problem with my recipe: there are _infinitely_many_ functions depending only on the rotation angle of $AB^{-1}$, which define a metric.

Comment: @IgorRivin:  The formula for the bi-invariant *Riemannian* distance $d(A,B)$ between two matrices $A,B\in\mathrm{SO}(3)$ is $$1+2\cos\bigl(d(A,B)\bigr) = \mathrm{tr}(AB^T).$$  There is no local coordinate system on $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ in which the function $d(A,B)$ itself is algebraic, let alone polynomial.  (This latter statement is also true for the standard Riemannian metric on $S^3$.)

Comment: @RobertBryant Thank you. But in fact, the Cayley-Menger thing is only relevant for the *chordal* distance between $A, B$ - I think part of the confusion in this answer is exactly the confusion between the two notions of isometric embedding (one, isometric as metric space, the other, isometric as inducing the same metric on the submanifold. For $S^3$ the chordal distance is $2\sin \theta/2,$ where $\theta$ is the actual distance, and the square of that is a polynomial function of the cosine *locally*.

Comment: I am bit confused. Do we consider isometric embedding of metric spaces or embedding as a manifold which defines a bi-invariant Riemannian structure?